# Query to delete all rows in a table hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql, delete-row

I am trying to delete all rows in table 'user_role' with hibernate query. But every time i am getting errors. Can someone please help me with it.

**DaoImpl**

```java
@Override
public void deleteAll() {
    session.getCurrentSession().delete(/*delete all query*/);
}
```

**model class**

```java
@Entity @Table(name="user_role")
public class User_Role {
    
    @Id @Column @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="role_name")
    private String name;
    
    //setter and getter 
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```java
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("delete from User_Role").executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You changed the capitalization of the table, which won't work in some DB engines. This shows that repeating the table name is not a good idea (difficult maintenance item).

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all instances of a class, one at a time, using this method. It's slower if you have many records, however, you're not duplicating the literal string for the table name.

```
public static void removeAllInstances(final Class<?> clazz) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();       
    session.beginTransaction();
    final List<?> instances = session.createCriteria(clazz).list();
    for (Object obj : instances) {
        session.delete(obj);
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

usage:

```
removeAllInstances(User_Role.class);
```

Comment: Use of generic 1 hit