# How to dynamically delete the rows of a table, or delete a table, with Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, hql

I have a table in an Oracle database.

I want to know how to delete its rows, or how to delete purely the table using Hibernate, **but not by changing the corresponding mapped class. I mean, I want to do it ouside the mapped class, in a main Java method for example.**

To read data, I always use native SQL queries with Hibernate.

To write data, I use `session.save`

But how do I do to delete data from a table, or delete the table ?

I looked at the Hibernate documentation, but the solution always involves changing the mapped class code by adding annotations...

I want a solution like the one I use to read and write data :

```
session.createSQLQuery("...");
```

Or

```
session.save(...);
```

Is there a solution like that ?

Comment: One workaround would be to create a database function that does this for you, and call it like a regular query.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another Stackoverflow question :

[Query to delete all rows in a table hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097385/query-to-delete-all-rows-in-a-table-hibernate)

If the table from which I want to delete the rows is named MyTable then, the answer is :

in HQL :

```
session.createQuery("delete from MyTable").executeUpdate();
```

in native SQL :

```
session.createSQLQuery("delete from MyTable").executeUpdate();
```

I should have looked longer in stackoverflow before posting this question, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

HQL `delete from Xyz` will help, as without `where` clause it will affect every row:

```
EntityManager em = // .. get EntityManager
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.createQuery("delete from MyTable").executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```